# Swift- Pass textfield from swift file to other swift file

Tags: ios, swift, request, pass-data

I am a newbie 
and I try to explain what my problem is:

I have a swift file its name is feedmodel.swift:

```
import Foundation



protocol FeedmodelProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class Feedmodel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {



    weak var delegate: FeedmodelProtocol!



    func downloadItems() {

        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://example.net/stock_service4.php");
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "Latitudee=19.4&Longitudee=-99.1";
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in


            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return

            }


            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
            self.parseJSON(data)

        }

        task.resume()

    }
```

and I have a swift file its name is NeuerBeitragViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class NeuerBeitragViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var Tankstelle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Kraftstoff1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Preis1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Kraftstoff2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Preis2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Notiz: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Longitude: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Latitude: UITextField!


    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var startLocation: CLLocation!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.delegate = self
        startLocation = nil
    }


    @IBAction func startWhenInUse(_ sender: Any) {

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {



        let latestLocation: CLLocation = locations[locations.count - 1]

        Latitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
                               latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        Longitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
                                latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


In my NeuerBeitragViewController.Swift 
I have this line:
Latitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
                                   latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
            Longitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
                                    latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
```

And I want to get the Value for Latitude.text and Longitude.text
in my Feedmodel.swift in this line here:

```
 let postString = "firstName=19.4&lastName=-99.1";
```

So that I can do this here:

```
let postString = "firstName=\(Latitude.text)&lastName=\Longitude.text";
```

Hope you guys understood what I need and can help.

Thank You!

Comment: You have to pass the `text` property of both textfields into `downloadItems` when you call it. Where do you actually call it anyway?

Comment: I don't know how you mean it

Answer (score 0):

To pass your information from one view to another you have several options :

- pass it through the segue (one to one)
- use protocols & delegates (one to one)
- use events & observers (one to many)
- use a third class responsible for holding the current data (one to many)

In your case, using **Protocols** & **Deleguates** is the proper option to choose.

Example provided [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBWu6TnhLeY).

Comment: Thank you very much can you please make an example I am a completely newbie